# JSON to xls in javascript

Tags: json, export, xls

Hi I am looking for a way to export JSON data to XLS file.I need to support IE9. I found the js-xlsx library, but it exports in xlsx format.Is there anyother way to export , I need to support multiple worksheets also.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try it with json2xls like this:

```
var json2xls = require('json2xls');
var json = {
    foo: 'bar',
    qux: 'moo',
    poo: 123,
    stux: new Date()
}

var xls = json2xls(json);

fs.writeFileSync('data.xlsx', xls, 'binary');
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2xls

Comment: Hi , I am not using node in my project. I was kind of lookinf for more independent library