# How to parse the nested data json data to explore the file in xslx format in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

> Hi im new to angularjs i need to explore the data in xlsx format but
>   im having my data in nested json array format which is not posiible to
>   explore the data in xlsx format.

index.html

```
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/FileSaver.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.7.12/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/alasql/0.3/alasql.min.js"></script>
    <div class="box-body">
    <button ng-click="exportData()" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right;margin-right:30px; margin-bottom:30px;">Export&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-arrow-do
wn"></i></button>
</div>
```

export.js

```
dashboard.controller('excelreportController',function($scope,$html){
 $scope.inverters = [
     {
         "InvDetails": "UPS",
         "LstRecords": [
           {
               "Id": 1,
               "Invertor_Id": 1,
               "Time_of_Reading": "20170214",
               "Lastreading": 0,
               "Readingby": 0
           },
           {
               "Id": 87,
               "Invertor_Id": 1,
               "Time_of_Reading": "20170215",
               "Lastreading": 5,
               "Readingby": 10
           },
           {
               "Id": 110,
               "Invertor_Id": 1,
               "Time_of_Reading": "20170216",
               "Lastreading": 10,
               "Readingby": 92
           },
           {
               "Id": 111,
               "Invertor_Id": 1,
               "Time_of_Reading": "20170216",
               "Lastreading": 92,
               "Readingby": 95
           }
         ]
     },
     {
         "InvDetails": "Power Supply",

         "LstRecords": [
           {
               "Id": 2,
               "Invertor_Id": 2,
               "Time_of_Reading": "20170214",
               "Lastreading": 0,
               "Readingby": 0
           },
           {
               "Id": 88,
               "Invertor_Id": 2,
               "Time_of_Reading": "20170215",
               "Lastreading": 7,
               "Readingby": 13
           },
           {
               "Id": 109,
               "Invertor_Id": 2,
               "Time_of_Reading": "20170216",
               "Lastreading": 13,
               "Readingby": 25
           },
           {
               "Id": 112,
               "Invertor_Id": 2,
               "Time_of_Reading": "20170216",
               "Lastreading": 25,
               "Readingby": 49
           }
         ]
     }
    ];
 $scope.exportData = function () {
        var data = "";
        $scope.headers = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.inverters, function (value, key) {

            var we = value.InvDetails;
            $scope.headers.push(we);
            $scope.last = value.LstRecords;
            angular.forEach($scope.last, function (value, key) {

                data = {
                    "Id": value.Id,
                    "Invertor_Id": value.Invertor_Id,
                    "Time_of_Reading": value.Time_of_Reading,
                    "Lastreading": value.Lastreading,
                    "Readingby": value.Readingby
                };
            })
        })

        $scope.result = [];
        $scope.result0 = [];

        $scope.result.push({
            "Invertor": JSON.stringify(data)
        })
        alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("john.xlsx",{headers:true}) FROM ?', [$scope.result]);
    };
```

please let me know any how to export this data in xlsx format using angularjs i have tried all the ways from more 24 hrs but i didnt get how to do please use my json data which i have give send me the working fiddle it will grate help for me in angularjs just i need to export my data in xlsx format.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30914247/json-to-xls-in-javascript. Json2xls works fine :)

Comment: I have tried this also but in sheet im not getting any data empty sheet is coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flatten your complex json to simple as follows.

```
var data = [
     {
         "InvDetails": "UPS",
         "LstRecords": [
           {
               "Id": 1,
               "Invertor_Id": 1,
               "Time_of_Reading": "20170214",
               "Lastreading": 0,
               "Readingby": 0
           },
           {
               "Id": 87,
               "Invertor_Id": 1,
               "Time_of_Reading": "20170215",
               "Lastreading": 5,
               "Readingby": 10
           },
           {
               "Id": 110,
               "Invertor_Id": 1,
               "Time_of_Reading": "20170216",
               "Lastreading": 10,
               "Readingby": 92
           },
           {
               "Id": 111,
               "Invertor_Id": 1,
               "Time_of_Reading": "20170216",
               "Lastreading": 92,
               "Readingby": 95
           }
         ]
     },
     {
         "InvDetails": "Power Supply",

         "LstRecords": [
           {
               "Id": 2,
               "Invertor_Id": 2,
               "Time_of_Reading": "20170214",
               "Lastreading": 0,
               "Readingby": 0
           },
           {
               "Id": 88,
               "Invertor_Id": 2,
               "Time_of_Reading": "20170215",
               "Lastreading": 7,
               "Readingby": 13
           },
           {
               "Id": 109,
               "Invertor_Id": 2,
               "Time_of_Reading": "20170216",
               "Lastreading": 13,
               "Readingby": 25
           },
           {
               "Id": 112,
               "Invertor_Id": 2,
               "Time_of_Reading": "20170216",
               "Lastreading": 25,
               "Readingby": 49
           }
         ]
     }
    ];
```

and then create a prototype for Array method as

```
Array.prototype.concatAll = function() {
  var results = [];
  this.forEach(function(subArray){
      subArray.forEach(function(item) {
          results.push(item);
      });
  })
  return results;
};
```

and after that you can simple use array map function to flatten your complex json to simple

```
var newData = 
      data.
        map(function(invertor){
          return invertor.LstRecords;
        }).
        concatAll();
console.log(newData)
```

Comment: data is not define is coming

Comment: i assign your complex json to data

Comment: i have assigned same as u did but still it is showing

Comment: but we are not getting invdetails names

Comment: so you want name as well as?

Comment: actually it should need to display according to the invdetails UPS invertor display one side and powersupply one side

Comment: there is just some change  update  the last code as
    `var newData = 
      data.
        map(function(invertor){
          return invertor.LstRecords.map(function(item) {
           item.InvDetails = invertor.InvDetails;
            return item
          })
        }).
        concatAll();
 console.log(newData)`

Comment: yes it is export the data hope u have done it should be disply according to that, i mean to say UPS details should be one side & power Supply details should be one side.. please let me know,Thanks

Comment: if it is possible u can send me that one as i asked, it should be need to be display according to table format please... Thanks

Comment: after 24 hours i got the answer i have tried in another data exporting in json format only...

Comment: so you want to export the data in xslx or you just want to show the data on html page

Comment: Both bro.. need to be display in the grid format for view and for export i need to fetch the data from API which sample data i have given u

Comment: export and html both i need to be do. tabel td's should be in loop

Comment: I understand what you want to do but for that you have to write some more code as well as custom angular filter for better code flow

Comment: haan we need to be but it should be in table format, inverter name which is UPS should be come on top at once and, then rest of the data which come under that it should be fallow.. next to that power supply table should be come..

Comment: I suggest just use a single table and make use of col span because its easy to export a single table rather than having multiple table

Comment: single table only  first i need to get headers in first page UPS and power supply in one linem next line date in one column  TimeOfReading in one column last reading in one column last readby which and all comes under in ups next power supply next to that but only 3 columns should be come next to that...totaly 7 columns.